# Android app main screen design

Tags: android, android-layout

Could someone point me to main screen pattern, when it's devided into 'table' like [here](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.audiko&feature=search_result):
It seems to me that it's the 'latest' android desing pattern, isn't it?
I need source code for smth like that. Would appreciate any help, thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google released the source for their IO schedule application here: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

It includes an example of the dashboard type UI you are looking for.

Good luck.

Comment: And someone based a tutorial on that: http://sacoinvest.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-build-dashboard-user-interface.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is a gridview.  Look here I used this source code in one of my apps:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/index.html is probably one of the better resources.  I would then do a search for various setups for differing phones so you can check you designs in as a large of sampling of phone screens as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found it well worth the hour to watch http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html