# how to create this image type layout?

Tags: android, layout

this is evernot app dashboard layout ...

[image: http://www.evernote.com/about/media/img/devices/android3_home.png]

how can i create this type of image button.. and also title bar ....

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782779/android-app-main-screen-design/5784548#5784548

Comment: @T0X1c :     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/b"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/projects"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonTest"
        android:paddingTop="60sp"
      
        android:text="Projects"></Button>

Comment: final answer : http://sacoinvest.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-build-dashboard-user-interface.html

Answer (score 1):

Below is only a guideline you have to modify it to gave it more professional look :P and suit your needs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/b"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/projects"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/ButtonTest"
    android:paddingTop="60sp"
    android:text="Projects"
    android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/b"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/projects"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/ButtonTest"
    android:paddingTop="60sp"
    android:text="Projects"
    android:layout_weight="1"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/b"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/projects"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/ButtonTest"
    android:paddingTop="60sp"
    android:text="Projects"
    android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/b"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/projects"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/ButtonTest"
    android:paddingTop="60sp"
    android:text="Projects"
    android:layout_weight="1"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think it is batter  http://sacoinvest.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-build-dashboard-user-interface.html